# Display full 1-128 bit decimal to binary using PHP

Tags: php, binary

I know this seams to be easy but, I have a question to this particular situation.
I already know how to convert decimal to binary using PHP, but I want to display
the full bit sequence, but surprisingly, I don't know how.

the conversion must be like this:

```
converting 127(decimal) to binary using PHP = 1111111. the bit sequence is 1-128 for every 
octet(IP Address) so this must output = 01111111 even 128 is not used.
2nd Example:
1(decimal) to binary = 01. Want to display the full 1-128 binary sequence even if
128,64,32,16,8,4,2 is not used it must be like this 00000001 not 01.
```

this is my PHP code:

```
<?php

        $octet1 = $_POST["oct1"];
        $octet2 = $_POST["oct2"];
        $octet3 = $_POST["oct3"];
        $octet4 = $_POST["oct4"];
        echo decbin($octet1) ," ", decbin($octet2) ," ", decbin($octet3) ," ", decbin($octet4);

    ?>
```

this only displays the shortened binary just like this:

```
16 to binary is 10000 or but i want to display this 00010000(Full length)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: so basically you want to zero-pad your output string? [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: Use str_pad() or sprintf to pad each octet to 8 characters with leading zeroes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using [**`sprintf`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) with **`b`** format specifier:

```
echo sprintf("%08b", 127);
// 01111111
echo sprintf("%08b.%08b.%08b.%08b", 127, 0, 0, 1);
// 01111111.00000000.00000000.00000001
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pad it:

```
echo str_pad($str, 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: second thing mate, I used your code wisely but how can I store the output of this to array

`str_pad(decbin($octets[$i]), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) , "&nbsp";`

this is the full code

`for($i=0;$i<=$octlenfnl;$i++){`
    `echo str_pad(decbin($octets[$i]),` `8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) , "&nbsp";`
    
   `}`

Comment: You can keep track of it in an array: `$arr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= $octlenfnl; $i++) { 
 $arr[] = str_pad(decbin($octets[$i]), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}`
//$arr contains all the values (no &nbsp;)
You can print it out similarly with a loop or `implode('&nbsp;', $arr)`;